# how to make widget scale up when it selected in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test, dart-polymer

I have an app that has `pageView.builder` and it contains 5 `stack` widget

how can I scale up the widget that user-selected, for example:

if the user scrolls to widget 3, widgets 1 & 2 become smaller than widget 3, and the same if he scrolls to widget 5 or 2

( the middle will become bigger than the widget on both sides)

my code :

```
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // ignore: sized_box_for_whitespace
    return Container(
      height: 320,
      child: PageView.builder(
          controller: pageController,
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
            return _bulidPageItem(position);
          }),
    );
  }

  Widget _bulidPageItem(int index) {

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Slide image 
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
      children: [
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5),
          height: 220,
          width: 350,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            color: index.isEven
                ? const Color(0xFFffd28d)
                : const Color(0xFF89dad0),
            image: const DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('images/chineseFood.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
        ),
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Slide Information 
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, right: 30, bottom: 15),
            height: 130,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                    blurRadius: 6,
                    spreadRadius: 0.7,
                    offset: const Offset(1, 4))
              ],
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
//------------------------------------------------
// Slider title
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  const BigText(
                    text: 'Chinese side',
                  ),
//----------------------------------------------
// Slider Rating
                  const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Wrap(
                        children: List.generate(
                          5,
                          (index) => const Icon(Icons.star,
                              color: AppColor.mainColor, size: 12),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      SmallText(text: 4.5.toString()),
                      const SizedBox(width: 10),
                      const SmallText(text: '1287 comments'),
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
//----------------------------------------------
// Slider Icons
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: const [
                      SliderIcons(
                          color: AppColor.iconColor1,
                          text: 'Normal',
                          icon: Icons.circle),
                      SliderIcons(
                          color: AppColor.mainColor,
                          text: '1.7km',
                          icon: Icons.location_pin),
                      SliderIcons(
                          color: AppColor.iconColor2,
                          text: '32min',
                          icon: FontAwesomeIcons.clock),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
  ],
);
```

}
}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [carousel slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) package provides the functionality you need. The package has an example, which exactly describes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should try out https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html

and for your layout, you can use rotate widget for the horizontal view and of course
you to use rotate widget on the child of the list too.

Answer (score 0):

Save the current page and adjust the content based on that. Like below the current page, `_currentPage == index`, has smaller margins.

```
final _pageController = PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8);
int _currentPage = 0;

...

PageView.builder(
  controller: _pageController,
  itemCount: 5,
  itemBuilder: (_, index) =>
    Container(
      margin: _currentPage == index 
        ? const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16)
        : const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 64),
      child: Image.network(
        'https://picsum.photos/1080/1920?index=$index', 
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        loadingBuilder: (_, child, loadingProgress) {
          if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } 
      )
    ),                
    onPageChanged: (page){
      setState(() {
        _currentPage = page;
      });
    },
  )
)
```